# What does the interferogram in Michelson interferometer mean about the topology of the specimen?

Tags: optics, interference, topology, interferometry

I'm want to know how can I evaluate the surface of a fibre by using the interferometer of Michelson.
The object beam in this method is reflected from the object and combined with the reference beam to form the fringes of constructive and destructive interference.

Comment: I'd be happy to try to answer your question.  But it is unclear what you are talking about when you say "evaluate the surface of a fibre".  I've never heard of the Michelson Morley interferometer being used to "evaluate" any "fibre".  I suppose you mean optical fibre.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to study the surface roughness of a polymeric fibre, and I have read that Michelson interferometer can be used to study the topology of the fibre.